# Failure of AM, GM inequality while trying find the minimum value of a function.

Tags: arithmetic, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The expression whose minimum value I'm trying to find is:
$$\displaystyle\frac{{ \sec{⁴}\alpha}}{{ \tan{²}\beta}}+\frac{{ \sec{⁴}\beta}}{{ \tan{²}\alpha}}$$

**I know there are many more methods to find the minimum value using the AMGM inequality. But I want to particularly stress on the following method because it does not give the right answer.**

$$\displaystyle\frac{{{\left({1}+{x}\right)}²}}{{{y}}}+\frac{{{\left({1}+{y}\right)}²}}{{{x}}}$$

Where x is tan²α and y is tan²β
$$\displaystyle f{{\left({x},{y}\right)}}=\displaystyle\frac{{{x}²}}{{y}}+\frac{{{y}²}}{{x}}+\frac{{{2}{y}}}{{x}}+\frac{{{2}{x}}}{{y}}+\frac{1}{{x}}+\frac{1}{{y}}$$

Now let this be f(x,y)
Apply AM GM inequality on all terms of f(x,y) to get

$$\displaystyle{A}{M}\ge{G}{M}$$

Apply this on the terms of f(x,y)

$$\displaystyle\frac{{ f{{\left({x},{y}\right)}}}}{{6}}\ge{\left[\frac{{{x}²}}{{y}}\cdot\frac{{{y}²}}{{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{{y}}\cdot\frac{{{2}{x}}}{{y}}\cdot\frac{{{2}{y}}}{{x}}\right]}^{{\frac{1}{{6}}}}$$

Simplify the RHS to get

$$\displaystyle\frac{ f{{\left({x},{y}\right)}}}{{6}}\ge{4}^{{\frac{1}{{6}}}}$$

Simplify to get
f(x,y) is greater than or equal to $$\displaystyle f{{\left({x},{y}\right)}}\ge{6}\cdot{2}^{{\frac{1}{{3}}}}$$

THIS NUMBER IN THE RHS IS APPROXIMATELY 7.55

why on earth do we get it's minimum value as 7.55 when we use this method, when the actual minimum value is 8. AMGM inequality is supposed to give the sharp minima.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the details of how you applied AMGM to obtain the result you display after "on all terms of f(x,y) to get". [AMGM is between arithmetic and geometric mean of two or more quantities. I'm asking for your set-up into what quantities and how the right side becomes $4^{1/6}.$

Comment: I see the minimum of $\sqrt {\frac {(1+x)^2}x}$ for positive $x$ to be $2$,  realized when $x=1$.  Thus the AM-GM inequality yields $4$, and multiplying by the $2$ we get from the average of the two terms yields $8$, as desired.  I don't understand your expression.

Comment: I regret the unclarity in the question question. Gimme a moment. I'll edit and fix it

Comment: Done. Kindly look into the problem now

Comment: But you see, from my earlier comment, that the AM-GM works as advertised if you just stick to the original two terms.  Splitting it up like this messes things up.  You can't have all the terms equal any more ($\frac {y^2}x=\frac 1x\implies y=1$ but $\frac {2y}x=\frac 1x\implies y=\frac 12$) thus you shouldn't expect to be able to realize the minimum the inequality yields.

Comment: @lulu How does it matter at all whether all terms are equal or not? (sorry I'm a dumbo)

Comment: For AM-GM, equality is realized when the terms are all equal.  In the two term version (sketched in my comment), this is illustrated:  equality occurs when both terms equal $2$, and therefore equal each other.  When you split it up into $6$ terms you lost that possibility. So..what you did was not wrong (the inequality you wrote is perfectly accurate) but it isn't sharp any more because you can't access the case where all terms are equal.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for the clarification. Well appreciated 

Comment: AM/GM only has equality when the individual values are equal. All you've shown is the minimum as $\geq 6\cdot 2^{1/3},$ with equality only possible if it is possible that all six terms are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The problem here is that, by dividing into $6$ asymmetric terms, you have made it impossible for all the terms to be equal, so you can't realize the inequality sharply.

To illustrate the problem, consider the usual AM-GM example:  $$x>0\implies x+\frac 1x≥2$$ as always, that bound is realized when the two terms are equal (hence when $x=1$).  Now suppose you split the left hand into four terms $$\frac x3+\frac {2x}3+\frac {1}{2x}+\frac 1{2x}$$
Now the terms can't be equal (as the second is always twice the first).  You can still apply AM-GM of course and now you get $$x+\frac 1x=\frac x3+\frac {2x}3+\frac {1}{2x}+\frac 1{2x}≥4\sqrt[4]{\frac 1{18}}=1.9419$$

Perfectly true, but not sharp.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum value $7.55$ in OP is not obtainable since

$$\frac{{{x}²}}{{y}}=\frac{{{y}²}}{{x}}=\frac{1}{{x}}=\frac{1}{{y}}=\frac{{{2}{x}}}{{y}}=\frac{{{2}{y}}}{{x}}$$
is impossible.

In order to get an
attainable minimum,
we have to split the sum of $6$ terms into two sums of four and two terms.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{(1+x)^2}{y}+\frac{(1+y)^2}{x} \\
= & \left(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y}{x}+\frac{y^2}{x}\right)+2\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\right) \\
\geqslant & 4 \sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{x^2}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{y^2}{x}}+2 \cdot 2 \sqrt{\frac{x}{y} \cdot \frac{y}{x}} \\
= & 4+4 \\
= & 8
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\quad &\textrm{The minimum value of 8 is attained}\\ & \Leftrightarrow \quad\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x^2}{y}=\frac{1}{x}=\frac{y^2}{x} \text { and } \frac{x}{y}=\frac{y}{x}\\ & \Leftrightarrow \quad x=y=1 \\
& \Leftrightarrow \quad \tan ^2 \alpha=\tan ^2 \beta=1
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score -3):

**Hint:** For $x, y > 0 \implies (1+x)^2 \ge 4x, (1+y)^2 \ge 4y$, and $\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{y}{x} \ge 2$. Can you finish it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's right, your method gives the minimum as 8... My question is, why does my method give the minimum value as 7.559 though the minimum value is 8

Comment: @BananaGenius: Your method as follows: $\dfrac{(1+x)^2}{y} + \dfrac{(1+y)^2}{x} = \dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac{2x}{y}+\dfrac{x^2}{y} + \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{2y}{x} + \dfrac{y^2}{x} \ge 6\sqrt[6]{......}$, and this equality cannot happen...

Comment: wdym the equality can't happen